# UI-codemirror Addons

Tags: angularjs, codemirror, ui-codemirror

I am using UI-codemirror in angularjs application for java code editing with mode set to 'text/x-java'. Now I want to use addons like autocomplete and lint.

for autocomplete I set options as below with keyup and also with onKeyUp, both the events are not triggered.

configure options in controller:

```
_this.editorOptions = {
        lineWrapping: true,
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode: 'text/x-java',
        smartIndent: true,
        tabSize: 4,
        indentWithTabs: true,
        tabindex: 4,
        autofocus: true,
        addModeClass: true,
        keyup: function (e, s) {
            console.log("Event Keyup");

        },
        onKeyUp: function (e, s) {
            console.log("Event Keyup");

        }
    }
```

Directive in the template:

```
<ui-codemirror ui-codemirror-opts="vm.editorOptions" ng-model="vm.activeQuestion.candidateAnswer"></ui-codemirror>
```

What are the addon js scripts to include and what configuration options to set for these to workout?

Comment: you are using Codemirror directive right? If you are using directive then your code is not right. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror

Comment: Yes, I have implemented as in the link only. Edited my question to show my implementation in detail.

Comment: There is an example you can see to check events :-
_editor.on("change", function(){ ... });

Answer (score 0):

Get access to the editor; after that you can register a listener on it :

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea);
myCodeMirror.on('change', function(codemirrorinstance)
{
    console.log(key pressed);
})
```